# Python list comprehension and list.remove()

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

The list signals_by_date stores tuples and each tuple contains 15 numbers. For each tuple within signals_by_date, I want to remove numbers that don't satisfy certain criteria. For some reason, no matter what constraints I put in the list comprehension, I'm always left with 7 numbers in each tuple. In the code example below, all numbers are less than 3, so I would expect each tuple to be empty. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
    signals_by_date = []
    for i in range(0, 1):
        temp_signals = []
        for symbol in symbols:        
            for signal in signals_by_symbol[symbol]:
            temp_signals.append(signal[i]-1)
        signals_by_date.append(temp_signals)
        [signals_by_date[i].remove(v) for v in signals_by_date[i] if v < 3]
```

Comment: Mind elaborating? I'm new to coding and completely self-taught, so I always welcome the opportunity to learn better practices. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to give an exact answer without actual data, but I'm fairly certain all this can be condensed into a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line should read:

```
signals_by_date[i] = [v for v in signals_by_date[i] if v >= 3]
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. But, what if I wanted to do something like this: signals_by_date[i] = [v for v in signals_by_date[i] if v <= -.02 and v >= .02]

Comment: Your condition will evaluate to false for every number. If you want numbers that are between -.02 and .02, you do: 
[v for v in x if -0.02 <= v <= 0.02]

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, as you remove each item you're shifting the items in the list such that you skip seeing every second one.

In general, I believe list comprehensions are intended to accrue new lists from existing ones rather than to produce side effects on the items in the original list; and certainly not to change the structure of the comprehended list.